# Qt Busy Processing dialog

Tags: c++, qt

I have an App that consumes lots of time running an algorithm. When the filter is running, the GUI obviously blocks until the algorithm is finished.

For that reason I want to show a modal dialog while the algorithm runs, displaying a "Busy" message. This way, the GUI would still be responsive. I tried doing it as follows:

```
dialog->setModal(true);
dialog->show();

// Run the code that takes up a lot of time
....

dialog->close();
```

However, this way the dialog shows up but it's all black (it's not drawn), Hoe can I solve this?

Comment: Your code in the comment is blocking the event loop processing most likely. Move it to another thread of execution.

Answer (score 3):

If GUI has to be responsive, heavy algorithm should run in non-main (non-GUI) thread.
To be responsive, GUI has to have access to main thread to process events in event loop.

You can use `QFuture` with `QtConcurrent::run` to implement this.

Example of `QFuture` usage:

```
TAlgoResult HeavyAlgorithm() {/* Here is algorithm routine */};
QFuture<TAlgoResult> RunHeavyAlgorithmAsync() 
{
    QtConcurrent::run([&](){return HeavyAlgorithm();});
}

// class which calls algo
class AlgoCaller
{
    QFutureWatcher<TAlgoResult> m_future_watcher;
    QDialog*                    mp_modal_dialog;

    AlgoCaller()
    {
        QObject::connect(&m_future_watcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, 
        [&]()
        {
            mp_modal_dialog->close(); // close dialog when calculation finished
        })
    }

    void CallAlgo() // to be called from main thread
    {
        mp_modal_dialog->show(); // show dialog before algo start
        m_future_watcher.setFuture(RunHeavyAlgorithmAsync()); 
            // start algo in background

        // main thread is not blocked and events can be processed
    }

};
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide an example?

Comment: @manatttta provided. please take a look if you can find it helpful

Comment: Careful, the `close` method is not thread safe, you cannot invoke it from another thread!